# Ensure that a user can only register my iPhone app once

Tags: iphone, unique, registration

I am creating an app where users will be given the opportunity to register with email, password, and all the other common stuff. But it is imperative that the user can only register once. Each user should only be able to register one time, with one email.

I am already using the unique device id to ensure that the user can only create one account for the device they are on. So for example if they reinstall the app, and try to create a new account with a different email, my server will detect that their device id has already been registered.

But my problem is this: if a user who already has an account goes to install the app on a ***different*** device, they would be able to register again using a different email. That is bad, because now one user has two accounts; and for what Im doing I can't allow this.

Is there any foreseeable way to stop situation like this? (thanks in advance)

Comment: So you want to psychically tell if a user is on device A or device B?

Comment: I sure hope you are not collecting their UDID without their consent...

Comment: @Wayne Would that be bad? What are the implications?

Comment: Removal from the App Store for violation of SDK terms. Criminal proceedings against you in jurisdictions where such data collection is illegal. Civil suit in other jurisdictions...

Comment: What happens when the user's devices dies and Apple gives them a replacement device (with a different UDID of course)?  Or they upgrade to the iPhone 6?  Will they be able to reregister their account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. You have no way of knowing the iTunes account of the user who installed your app, so you have no way to tell whether two devices belong to the same user **unless the user chooses to let you know** (some of the apps I've worked on have a 'link devices' feature to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to identify the user of an app across multiple devices without that user choosing to identify themselves. Anyone who downloads your app is free to install it on however many devices they own.

In addition what you describe doing above will have unintended negative consequences for your users.

> I am already using the unique device id to ensure that the user can only create one account for the device they are on. So for example if they reinstall the app, and try to create a new account with a different email, my server will detect that their device id has already been registered.

Consider what happens when a user gives their device to someone else. Now anyone who purchases a used device or just switches the iTunes account associated with a device is unable to use your app. Even if they are a legitimate new user who purchased their own copy.

I think that you need a new restriction scheme.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be fair at all. If you would disable to install the application on multiple devices, when the user changes her/his phone the application would have to be purchased again.
However iTunes will tell the user that this application is already purchased, so you just get ended up with an non-functional application ...

So the answer is you can't, but on the other hand you shouldn't ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are looking for a way to physically identify the actual person that is using the device. Unfortunately for you (and fortunately for me and millions of other regula users :-)) the technology is not there yet.

The best you can hope is being able to identify the iTunes account linked to particular device. But even in that case, there is no reasonable way you can know it's the same user. For example, I have iPhone and iPad, both using the same iTunes account, but the iPad is mostly used by my wife, and most of the apps there are linked to her own online accounts (email, Facebook, Twitter and so on). And I know other people that have one iTunes account, used on several devices, where the primary user is a different person.

In addition, you shouldn't block account creation based on device Id. If a user of yours sold their iPhone, the new owner will be unable to use your app, as he won't be able to register, yet he won't (and shouldn't) have access to the old owner account.